# How to update API in API in API Manager?

Tags: api, mule

I created a RAML file in API Design, then deployed in API manager and implemented in API runtime manager. It is clear no issues now.

Now i got change in raml file. I did changes in API Design and published into exchange with v2.

The problem here is how to import the v2 API into API manager ? 
after importing the new api do i need to add all policies applied on v1 API to v2 API again ?

or is there any automatic option ?

I don't find any options in API manager, please help me..,

Answer (score 1):

[image]Yes, we need to apply policies again. Even when there is the same API version have 2 instances.
If you do not have major change then you can just go to action and upgrade to next assent version of the same API. Else you need to apply policies.

Ranveer

Comment: thanks, how to import the v2 API into API manager from exchange where i loaded v2 of the api ?

Comment: Same way as you create the first time. In the configuration, it will ask for version and assent version so you can select from drop down.